# Can Puppeteer upload files to "input type=file"?

Tags: puppeteer

I tried many codes I found on the web.
But they did not work.

This code created by ChatGPT(Model-4).

```
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "filefullpath.png");
    const inputSelector = 'input[type=file]';

    let inputUploadHandle = await page.$(inputSelector);
    await inputUploadHandle.uploadFile(filePath);
```

Tell me the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that approach looks correct.
In provided example it's better to use `waitForSelector` except `$`.
File upload can be done via code below:

```js
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, fileName); // file is stored in current test's package
const input = await page.waitForSelector(inputSelector);
await input.uploadFile(filePath);
```

Comment: But I got an error message.
ProtocolError: DOM.setFileInputFiles timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.
    at new Callback (C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\uploadTest\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:62:35)
    at CallbackRegistry.create

Comment: @vr_min_chan have you tried to increase timeout in `puppeteer.launch({ protocolTimeout: 120000})` ?